# JS Search function to appear the list of text in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, web

so i created a JS search function with purpose to search a body of text in HTML(hardcoded text content) so basically theres a search box for user to input for example maybe a line within a subpoint, example: If remote support fails, MIS may request the user to bring their PC to MIS department for further rectification if required.

the current code kinda works, but certain thing doesnt appear, for example if i search "General IT Policy" all of its subpoint will appear as well but this doesnt work for others.

Here is my HTML and JS file

```js
function searchCont() {
    var input, filter, ol, li, a, i, j, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("searchInput2");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ol = document.querySelector(".middle");
    li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
  
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      var lines = li[i].getElementsByTagName("span");
      for (j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
        var line = lines[j];
        txtValue = line.textContent || line.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
          break;
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <!----======== CSS ======== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <!----===== Boxicons CSS ===== -->
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    
    <!-- CALL JS -->
    <script src="sidebar.js"></script>
    <script src="search.js"></script>
    <script src="searchcont.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="sidebar close">
        <header>
            <div class="image-text">
                <span class="image">
                    <img src="logo.png" alt="">
                </span>

                <div class="text logo-text">
                    <span class="name">MIS KANEKA</span>
                    <span class="profession">IT POLICY</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <i class='bx bx-chevron-right toggle'></i>
        </header>

        <div class="menu-bar">
            <div class="menu">

                <li class="search-box">
                    <i class='bx bx-search-alt icon'></i>
                    <input type="text" id="searchInput" onkeyup="searchList()" placeholder="Search...">
                </li>

                <ul class="menu-links" id="list">
                    <li class="nav-link">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <i class='bx bx-desktop
                            -alt icon' ></i>
                            <span class="text nav-text">01: General IT Policy</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-link">
                        <a href="systems.html">
                            <i class='bx bx-lock icon' ></i>
                            <span class="text nav-text">02: IT Systems Security</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-link">
                        <a href="password.html">
                            <i class='bx bx-key icon'></i>
                            <span class="text nav-text">03: Password Policy</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-link">
                        <a href="user.html">
                            <i class='bx bx-user-circle icon' ></i>
                            <span class="text nav-text">04: User Privileges</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-link">
                        <a href="internet.html">
                            <i class='bx bx-wifi icon' ></i>
                            <span class="text nav-text">05: Internet Connectivity</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-link">
                        <a href="asset.html">
                            <i class='bx bx-file icon' ></i>
                            <span class="text nav-text">06: Asset Control Policy</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-link">
                        <a href="server.html">
                            <i class='bx bx-server icon' ></i>
                            <span class="text nav-text">07: Server Room Security</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-link">
                        <a href="service.html">
                            <i class='bx bx-user-check icon' ></i>
                            <span class="text nav-text">08: Service Request Policy</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="bottom-content">
                

                <li class="mode">
                    <div class="sun-moon">
                        <i class='bx bx-moon icon moon'></i>
                        <i class='bx bx-sun icon sun'></i>
                    </div>
                    <span class="mode-text text">Dark mode</span>

                    <div class="toggle-switch">
                        <span class="switch"></span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                
            </div>
        </div>

    </nav>

    <section class="home">
        <div class="text">
            <input type="text" id="searchInput2" onkeyup="searchCont()" placeholder="Search...">

            <h1>General IT Policy</h1>
            <ol class="middle">
                <li>
                    <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">General IT Policy</span>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            It is the responsibility of every user to identify and communicate support
                            <div class="line-2">
                                issues with MIS team via IT helpdesk. However, if any issue that requires
                                immediate attention (e.g. unable to make a conference call, unable to log
                                in to own PC, etc.) the user may contact any MIS personnel directly for
                                immediate support (refer to Service Level Agreement (SLA) in Addendum
                                1).
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            The first level of support to rectify user’s issue will be done through a
                            <div class="line-2">
                                remote support session.
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            If remote support fails, MIS may request the user to bring their PC to MIS
                            <div class="line-2">
                                department for further rectification if required.
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            MIS team members shall only support within MIS department
                            <div class="line-2">
                                jurisdiction/job scope.
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">Naming Convention</span>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            Complying to Global IT direction, all standardization of naming
                            <div class="line-2">
                                convention for laptops/desktops, shall follow as per the standard below:
                                <div class="line-2">
                                    Standard: CountryRunningNumber
                                </div>
                                <div class="line-2">
                                    Sample: MY0615
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Standardization of naming convention for user’s ID and email address shall
                            <div class="line-2">
                                follow as per the standard below:
                                <div class="line-2">
                                    <strong>
                                        Windows ID: FirstName.LastName
                                    </strong>
                                </div>
                                <div class="line-2">
                                    <strong>
                                        Email: FirstName.LastName@kaneka.com.my
                                    </strong>
                                </div>
                                <div class="line-2">
                                    Sample:
                                </div>
                                <div class="line-2">
                                    Shankar Supramaniam - shankar.supramaniam&#64;...
                                </div>
                                <div class="line-2">
                                    Ong Kien Soon - kiensoon.ong&#64;...
                                </div>
                                <div class="line-2">
                                    Steven Lim Guan Eng – steven.lim&#64;...
                                </div>
                                <div class="line-2">
                                    Wan Adri Idzwan bin Wan Mansor - idzwan.mansor&#64;...
                                </div>
                                <div class="line-2">
                                    Kimura Takuya - takuya.kimura&#64;...
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            All PCs will be <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">labelled with a hostname.</span> Users are responsible for
                            <div class="line-2">
                                contacting the MIS team and collecting the new label if the existing label
                                has peeled off or has thoroughly worn-out.
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">Staff Updates</span>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            Shall there be any  <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;"> employee onboarding, offboarding or updates,</span>
                            <div class="line-2">
                                MIS will update or delete user’s credential used in every system based on
                                <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">ticket raised by HR via IT Helpdesk - Employees</span> ticket.
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            In any event of 3.1, MIS department should be notified <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;"> before</span> the effective
                            <div class="line-2">
                                date of the last date in office.<span style="display: inline-block; font-style:italic;">
                                    (refer to Service Level Agreement (SLA) in
                                    Addendum 1).
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Any request to <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">divert email ID</span> shall come from HOD before the last date
                            <div class="line-2">
                                of service of the employee. If <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">NO</span> such information is received, MIS
                                reserves the right to act upon the user’s data or account by <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">deleting</span> or
                                <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">blocking</span> the user’s access after <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">5.30 pm</span> on the <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">last service date.</span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Shall the <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">last date</span> of service fall on <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">Saturday, Sunday or public</span>
                            <div class="line-2">
                                <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">holiday</span>, MIS will <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">block</span> the access on the <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">last service date before</span> the
                                above mentioned days. Any request to shorten or <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">prolonged</span> the date
                                shall be notified to MIS by <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">HOD</span>.
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">Shared Calendar Settings</span>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            All email users shall not set their calendar busy/free as default.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            If the meeting is private and confidential, users can set the meeting as
                            Private.
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IMPORTANT TO NOTE, ignore the first search function on my sidebar, that works fine, i didnt realize i copy the whole code

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking whether the *input* value exist in the *header* element. If exist then reset the *style* and *return* from the function:

```
if(document.querySelector('#headerTitle').textContent.toLowerCase().includes(input.value.toLowerCase())){
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    li[i].style.display = "";
  }
  return true;
}
```

**Please Note:** I have added the *id attribute* in the *header* element and used *oninput* event instead of *onkeyup*:

```
<h1 id="headerTitle">General IT Policy</h1>
```

**Demo:**

```js
function searchCont() {
    var input, filter, ol, li, a, i, j, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("searchInput2");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ol = document.querySelector(".middle");
    li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
   
    //check here 
    if(document.querySelector('#headerTitle').textContent.toLowerCase().includes(input.value.toLowerCase())){
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
      }
      return true;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      var lines = li[i].getElementsByTagName("span");
      for (j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
        var line = lines[j];
        txtValue = line.textContent || line.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
          break;
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
    
  }
```

```html
<div class="bottom-content">

    <li class="mode">
        <div class="sun-moon">
            <i class='bx bx-moon icon moon'></i>
            <i class='bx bx-sun icon sun'></i>
        </div>
        <span class="mode-text text">Dark mode</span>

        <div class="toggle-switch">
            <span class="switch"></span>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>

<section class="home">
  <div class="text">
      <input type="text" id="searchInput2" oninput="searchCont()" placeholder="Search...">

      <h1 id="headerTitle">General IT Policy</h1>
      <ol class="middle">
          <li>
              <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">General IT Policy</span>
              <ol>
                  <li>
                      It is the responsibility of every user to identify and communicate support
                      <div class="line-2">
                          issues with MIS team via IT helpdesk. However, if any issue that requires
                          immediate attention (e.g. unable to make a conference call, unable to log
                          in to own PC, etc.) the user may contact any MIS personnel directly for
                          immediate support (refer to Service Level Agreement (SLA) in Addendum
                          1).
                      </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      The first level of support to rectify user’s issue will be done through a
                      <div class="line-2">
                          remote support session.
                      </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      If remote support fails, MIS may request the user to bring their PC to MIS
                      <div class="line-2">
                          department for further rectification if required.
                      </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      MIS team members shall only support within MIS department
                      <div class="line-2">
                          jurisdiction/job scope.
                      </div>
                  </li>
              </ol>
          </li>
          <li>
              <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">Naming Convention</span>
              <ol>
                  <li>
                      Complying to Global IT direction, all standardization of naming
                      <div class="line-2">
                          convention for laptops/desktops, shall follow as per the standard below:
                          <div class="line-2">
                              Standard: CountryRunningNumber
                          </div>
                          <div class="line-2">
                              Sample: MY0615
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      Standardization of naming convention for user’s ID and email address shall
                      <div class="line-2">
                          follow as per the standard below:
                          <div class="line-2">
                              <strong>
                                  Windows ID: FirstName.LastName
                              </strong>
                          </div>
                          <div class="line-2">
                              <strong>
                                  Email: FirstName.LastName@kaneka.com.my
                              </strong>
                          </div>
                          <div class="line-2">
                              Sample:
                          </div>
                          <div class="line-2">
                              Shankar Supramaniam - shankar.supramaniam&#64;...
                          </div>
                          <div class="line-2">
                              Ong Kien Soon - kiensoon.ong&#64;...
                          </div>
                          <div class="line-2">
                              Steven Lim Guan Eng – steven.lim&#64;...
                          </div>
                          <div class="line-2">
                              Wan Adri Idzwan bin Wan Mansor - idzwan.mansor&#64;...
                          </div>
                          <div class="line-2">
                              Kimura Takuya - takuya.kimura&#64;...
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      All PCs will be <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">labelled with a hostname.</span> Users are responsible for
                      <div class="line-2">
                          contacting the MIS team and collecting the new label if the existing label
                          has peeled off or has thoroughly worn-out.
                      </div>
                  </li>
              </ol>
          </li>
          <li>
              <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">Staff Updates</span>
              <ol>
                  <li>
                      Shall there be any  <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;"> employee onboarding, offboarding or updates,</span>
                      <div class="line-2">
                          MIS will update or delete user’s credential used in every system based on
                          <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">ticket raised by HR via IT Helpdesk - Employees</span> ticket.
                      </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      In any event of 3.1, MIS department should be notified <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;"> before</span> the effective
                      <div class="line-2">
                          date of the last date in office.<span style="display: inline-block; font-style:italic;">
                              (refer to Service Level Agreement (SLA) in
                              Addendum 1).
                          </span>
                      </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      Any request to <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">divert email ID</span> shall come from HOD before the last date
                      <div class="line-2">
                          of service of the employee. If <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">NO</span> such information is received, MIS
                          reserves the right to act upon the user’s data or account by <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">deleting</span> or
                          <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">blocking</span> the user’s access after <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">5.30 pm</span> on the <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">last service date.</span>
                      </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      Shall the <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">last date</span> of service fall on <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">Saturday, Sunday or public</span>
                      <div class="line-2">
                          <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">holiday</span>, MIS will <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">block</span> the access on the <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">last service date before</span> the
                          above mentioned days. Any request to shorten or <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">prolonged</span> the date
                          shall be notified to MIS by <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">HOD</span>.
                      </div>
                  </li>
              </ol>
          </li>
          <li>
              <span style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">Shared Calendar Settings</span>
              <ol>
                  <li>
                      All email users shall not set their calendar busy/free as default.
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      If the meeting is private and confidential, users can set the meeting as
                      Private.
                  </li>
              </ol>
          </li>
      </ol>
  </div>
</section>
```